# Object Mapper in Vertx 4

Tags: java, objectmapper, jackson-databind

How to convert Object Mapper to make it work properly in Vertx 4?

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new CaseFormatRemappingJsonFactory());`

Answer (score 0):

1. create new factory for ObjectMapper
2. add CaseFormatRemappingJsonFactory to mapper
3. fix objectMapper to mapper in vertx 4
4. add adapter ObjectMapperJsonAdapter to vertx 4

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> future) throws Exception {

    Handler<Message<Employee>> handler = message -> {

      log.info("Received a message: " + message);

      Employee employee = message.body();

      // do something with the employee json here...

      log.info("employee after processing: " + employee);
    };

    // get reference to event bus on this verticle's context (aka instance) - see below how it is set up in the VertxOptions class and extended by Vertx4OptionSupport class in the root pom file..
    EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

    // #1 create jettison json factory from Jackson 2 : OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here... OK works both with Vert x 4 and with Vert x 3 (with Jackson 2 wrapper) here...

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JettisonMappedXmlFactory());

    // #2 add CaseFormatRemappingJsonFactory to mapper
    // mapper.setJsonFactory(new CaseFormatRemappingJsonFactory());
    // #3 fix objectMapper to mapper in vertx 4
    mapper.configure(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    // #4 add adapter ObjectMapperJsonAdapter to vertx 4
    MessageCodec<Employee> employeeCodec = MessageCodec.jsonObjectMapper(mapper);

    eb.consumer("employee", employeeCodec, handler);

  }
}
```